# How to set a particular site to attack in zed attack proxy and exclude other sites?

Tags: zap

I am trying to run my selenium script and running zap in background. But after my scripts get pass I want to attack only my site and want to exclude others.

How to exclude all sites except the site I want to scan?

Answer (score 1):

ZAP will only attack what you tell it to attack. It will only attack 'everything' in 'ATTACK' mode, which you shouldnt use in this situation. If you can explain exactly how you are using ZAP then we'll be able to tell you how to use ZAP safely.

Answer (score 0):

Include in Context the thing(s) you want to assess. You can then spider and scan with that defined Context as your target (vs. URL(s)).

Information on defining context is available here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsSessionContexts